# How to keep a thread on hold in a method untill another therad Ends in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 2 Methods, One method call the other. thread is declared inside the 2nd method and that method will return a boolean output. so when i call the 2nd method i cant control the output, and 1st method returns the success message before the thread ends. I want the boolean output after when the thread ends. How can i control this?

1st Method

```
private void AccessElements()
{
    TaxoProcess Taxo = new TaxoProcess();
    if (Taxo.AccessEntity())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Extracted Data", "Extract Application", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }

}
```

2nd Method,

```
public bool AccessEntity()
{
    try
    {
        bool Status = true;

        Thread MainThread =  Thread.CurrentThread;

        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Entities.Count; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Dispatcher.FromThread(MainThread).BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    int PercentageValue = (int)(0.5f + ((100f * i) / Entities.Count));
                    StaticDataProperties.ProgBar.Value = PercentageValue;                        
                }));                    
            }
        }));

        backgroundThread.Start();

       return Status;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorException = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should look at `async`/`await`.  If you go down this road, the end result will be you just block until it's finished.  I would imagine that defeats the purpose of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem you could use [`Thread.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx) and do this, place this logic before `return` statement..

```
backgroundThread.Join(); // blocks calling thread.
```

Comment: Thax, That will do.

Comment: @Dinukshi Jayarathne if this is the answer, you could/should mark it also accordingly

Comment: @Hari Prasad Actually it didnt work, when i put some heavy cord inside the for loop,  the cord stooped working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using threads which use too much memory you can use Tasks and async/await like Charles Mager suggested

```
private async void AccessElements()
{
    TaxoProcess Taxo = new TaxoProcess();
    if (await Taxo.AccessEntity())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Extracted Data", "Extract Application", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
}

public async Task<bool> AccessEntity()
{

    return Task.Run(() =>
        {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Entities.Count; i++)
            {
               await Task.Delay(100);

                int PercentageValue = (int)(0.5f + ((100f * i) / Entities.Count));
                StaticDataProperties.ProgBar.Value = PercentageValue;
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorException = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This is shorter and does all the thread managements in the background

Comment: You need to `await` the `Task.Delay`, and you [should prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: it returns a error 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: It returns the catch i assume?

Comment: Maybe EntitiesCount is not set. I don't think its a thread problem though, object ref

Answer (score 0):

There's two general directions you can attempt to take:

Dirty approach:
Add a temprary boole that is true while the "inner" thread is still running and handle the logic that should be handled after this after a "while"-statement on that boole.
(the while-statement would keep the code looping/"paused" untill the boole's value is falsey)

Neat approach:
Using async tasks and a callback function.